# In react.js, is it better to call an external API upon form submission or within componentDidMount() of subsequent component?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.js and I have been struggling with understanding what's the best practice on when to call an external API. I currently have a form that collects some data. I want to use this data to make a POST request, receive some data back and display that data via a new component. My vague understanding suggests that I can do this in two ways:

**Option 1:** Call API and get results within the form component, then redirect to new route (along with results)

**Option 2:** Redirect to new route (along with form data), then call API within componentDidMount() of new component

I can't really tell what is the best way to handle this. In a way, Option 1 sounds more suitable to me given that it seems to achieve better separation of concerns. Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the redux approach, and separate the logic from your components.
This way, you define the actions that call the API and gets the result, the reducers that decide how to store the results in a global state, and the containers that provides the data and functions to components ([redux](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter-vanilla)). You can archive a similar result using React context too. The main point here is that your components are completely decoupled from the logic and the global state.

Take a look at this example: [example](https://redux.js.org/basics/example)

Answer (score 0):

in my case, axios npm is very suitable solution to fix some issues such as yours. 
for example, you can try this : 
first -- you should install axios npm.

```
npm install axios --save
```

and then, in your component,

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

I think that the best solution to fetch data is that call axios in componentwillmount method.

```
axios.post('/api/path', data).then(res => {
//here is your action.
}).catch(err => {console.log(err)});
```

this is very simple introduction about axios in react.
if you have more issues, let me know. good luck.